# Problem with importing helper. Any advice?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, helper

I'd like to import hleper in jupyter notebook, but I've got Traceback error. There were no ml_metrics, but now is installed. Now I have another error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quadratic_weighted_kappa'" and I don't know how to add/install this module.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5bx2.png)

Comment: Explain how you installed the packages.

Comment: in terminal 'pip install ml-metrics'